# Flash file loads much before than its background sound in website ! Help

Tags: flash, audio, web

I have a website at www.enigmafest.com ! You may try opening it ! The problem i'm facing is that after the preloader is done the homepage comes but the other menus still takes much time to load and the sound also take atleast 5 min ! :(

How can i make them all bind together so that after the preloader everything comes together at an instant completely !

Answer (score 0):

Just add a progress in the bottom right corner to show that the sound is loading. The sound is not needed for your website to work so let it load in the background.

Most likely, users won't really mind since they are used to stuff being loaded progressively on websites, and many don't even like sounds on website so you're doing them a favor :-)